# Is this possible to validate a form created without formBuilder?

Tags: php, symfony

As I say in the title. I have create a form in a twig file

```
<form action="{{ path('domain_confirm') }}" method="post" id="choose-domain-form">
   {% for domain, price in data %}
       <tr>
           <td>
               {{ domain }}
           </td>
           <td></p>{{ price }} €</td>
           <td><input class="domain-purchase-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="domaintest" value="{{ domain }}" data-price="{{ price }}"></td>
       </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</form>
```

How can I validate this form and get datas from this form inside my Controller ?

When I try to get these datas with

```
$request->request->get('form');
```

I get a `null` response

Do you have some ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

As for the validation, you will have to create a form with the formBuilder and validate it that way. You can however, validate your input using the Symfony Validators, but this is not advised.

I strongly suggest using the provided form builder as it has alot of features you want such as CRSF and well... validation, aswel as auto mapping onto your entities.

As for getting the data in this specific case you will need to call :

```
$request->request->all();
```

However, i see all your checkboxes will have the same "name" attribute, you will need to change it from `name="domaintest"` to `name="domaintest[]"`.
When you call :

```
$request->request->get('domaintest');
```

You will receive an array with values.